# How to check if a method exists using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to write a nice clean check whether a method exists or not:

```
expect(subscriber.respond_to?(:fake_method)).to be(true)    <-- This fails (as expected)

expect(subscriber).respond_to?(:fake_method)                <-- This passes, why?
```

The fake_method does not exist, but when I use the second convention, my test passes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe I have the answer. The second convention doesn't work because the matcher is different according to the documentation:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/respond-to-matcher

You should try with:

```
expect(subscriber).to respond_to(:fake_method)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Kryptman, but I got an error: `ArgumentError: The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to '#to'.`

Comment: Doh!  you are right, but need to remove the question mark, your link helped for sure: `expect(subscriber).to respond_to(:fake_method)`

Comment: Updated! I'm glad that was useful Mark :)

Answer (score 1):

we can simply use `expect(subscriber).not_to respond_to(:fake_method)` for negative case.